# NServiceBus Unit of Work For Multitenancy with Custom ORM

Tags: multithreading, orm, nservicebus, multi-tenant, unit-of-work

Here are my parameters:

- Simple NServiceBus Saga implementation using the default builder
- In-house ORM on top of SQL Server
- Multitenancy - I have two ASP.NET MVC 4 domains running on the same website, each with their own databases

We configure our ORM using a static method like so:

```
public class EndpointConfig: IConfigureThisEndpoint, IWantCustomInitialization {
  public void Init() {
    var bus = Configure.With()
      .AutofacBuilder()
      .UnicastBus().LoadMessageHandlers().DoNotAutoSubscribe()
      .XmlSerializer()
      .MsmqTransport().IsTransactional(true).PurgeOnStartup(false)
      .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
      .Sagas().RavenSagaPersister().InstallRavenIfNeeded()
      .UseInMemoryTimeoutPersister()
      .CreateBus()
      .Start();

     SlenderConfiguration.Init(bus);
  }
}

public class SlenderCofnigruation {
  private static ORMScope scope { get; set; }

  public static void Init(IBus bus)
  {
    ORMConfig.GetScope = () =>
    {
       var environment = "dev";
       if (bus.CurrentMessageContext.Headers.ContainsKey("Environment"))
         environment = bus.CurrentMessageContext.Headers["Environment"];

       if (scope == null)
         scope = new SlenderScope(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[environment].ConnectionString);
      return scope;
    };
  }
}
```

This works fine in our single-tenant Beta environment - it's fine for that static scope to get re-used because the environment header is always the same for a given deployment.

It's my understanding that this *won't* work for the multitenant situation described above, because NServiceBus will reuse threads across messages. The same scope would then be used, causing problems if the message was intended for a different environment.

What I think I want is a single scope per message, but I'm really not sure how to get there.

I've seen [Unit Of Work Implementation for RavenDB](http://nservicebus.com/UnitOfWorkImplementationForRavenDB.aspx), and the unit of work implementation in the full duplex sample, but I'm not sure that's the right path.

I've also seen the DependencyLifecycle enum, but I'm not sure how I can use that to resolve the scope given the way I have to set up the GetScope func.

Obviously I have no idea what's going on here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do something on a per-message basis, consider using message mutators (IMutateIncomingMessages) in addition to your unit-of-work management with some thread-static state.